Numerically solving the Advection-diffusion equation with no-flux boundary condition results in violation of mass conservation
I am trying to solve numerically the advection-diffusion equation of the following form
$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial t}=\alpha\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial x^2}+\beta \frac{\partial C}{\partial x}$$
with no flux BCs namely
$$\alpha\frac{\partial C}{\partial x}+\beta C=0$$
at x=0 and x=L.
I solve this as one would normally solve the diffusion equation, namely by using finite differences and the forward euler algorithm.
$$C_N(t+dt)=C_N(t)+dt\left(\alpha\frac{C_{N+1}(t)-2C_N(t)+C_{N-1}(t)}{dx^2}+\beta\frac{C_{N+1}(t)-C_{N-1}(t)}{2dx}\right)$$
The BC's I implement via the ghost point method i.e N=n+1 and N=0 are excluded and eliminated via the boundary conditions. For N=1 we get
$$\alpha\frac{C_{2}-C_{0}}{2dx}+\beta C_1=0$$
or
$$C_{0}=C_{2}+\frac{2dx\beta}{\alpha}C_1$$
and for N=n
we get similarly
$$C_{n+1}=C_{n-1}-\frac{2dx\beta}{\alpha}C_n$$
which gives us the time-evolution equations at the boundary as
$$C_1(t+dt)=C_1(t)+dt\left(\alpha\frac{2C_{2}(t)-2C_1(t)+\frac{2dx\beta}{\alpha}C_1(t)}{dx^2}+\frac{\beta^2}{\alpha}C_1\right)$$
and
$$C_n(t+dt)=C_n(t)+dt\left(\alpha\frac{2C_{n-1}(t)-2C_n(t)-\frac{2dx\beta}{\alpha}C_n(t)}{dx^2}+\frac{\beta^2}{\alpha}C_n\right)$$.
Now when I try to solve this numerically mass is not conserved, but the mass non-conservation can also easily be seen from considering the system initially being of homogenous concentration $C_0$. During the first iteration all the interior points remains fixed while at the boundary we get
$$C_n(t+dt)=C_0+dt\left(\alpha\frac{-\frac{2dx\beta}{\alpha}C_0}{dx^2}-\frac{\beta^2}{\alpha}C_0\right)$$
and
$$C_1(t+dt)=C_0+dt\left(\alpha\frac{\frac{2dx\beta}{\alpha}C_0}{dx^2}-\frac{\beta^2}{\alpha}C_0\right)$$.
Now this clearly does not conserve the mass of the system as it should per the no-flux boundary conditions. What is causing this?
Code can also be found here
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# 2. Set up parameters
nx = 101
dx = 0.01
nt = 20000
alpha = 0.1
beta=-1
dt = 0.0001

# 3. Initial conditions

q = np.ones(nx)

qn= q.copy()


# 4. Solving the PDE
for n in range(nt):


    qn=q.copy()

    q[1] = qn[1] + alpha * dt / dx ** 2 * (qn[2]-2*qn[1]+qn[2]+2*dx*(beta/alpha)*qn[1]) +\
          ( beta*dt/(2*dx))*(qn[2] - (qn[2]+2*dx*(beta/alpha)*qn[1]))
    for i in range(2, nx-2):
        
        
        q[i] = qn[i] + alpha * dt / dx ** 2 * (qn[i+1]-2*qn[i]+qn[i-1]) +\
          ( beta*dt/(2*dx))*(qn[i+1] - qn[i-1])
        
    q[nx-2] = qn[nx-2] + alpha * dt / dx ** 2 * (qn[nx-3]-2*qn[nx-2]+(qn[nx-3]-(beta/alpha)*2*dx*qn[nx-2])) +\
           beta*dt/(2*dx)*(-qn[nx-3] +(qn[nx-3]-(beta/alpha)*2*dx*qn[nx-2]) )


# 5. Plot results
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 1, 101), q)



plt.xlim(dx, 1-dx)
plt.show()```


Typically a "no-flux" boundary condition is a Neumann type boundary condition, i.e $\frac{\partial C}{\partial x}=0$ at $x=0,L$. For certain values of $\alpha,\beta$, the lack of conservation is obvious, e.g, take $(\alpha,\beta)=(0,1).$

My suggestion is to use the variable transformation $\xi=x+\beta t$ to transform into the standard heat equation.
